# Hi, I am using extent report in specflow+c#, i want to print my API response in extent report in Then step, but I am not sure how do I do that

Tags: c#, specflow, extentreports

I want to print details of my API response like statusCode, StatusMessage and more importantly response content(JSON format) in my extent report of specflow project.
Can anyone please give me solution to this.

not sure what needs to be coded for this but i know this is possible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to add custom logs to the Gherkin test narrative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76303465/is-it-possible-to-add-custom-logs-to-the-gherkin-test-narrative)